# Ant target for building protocol buffer files

Tags: java, ant, protocol-buffers

Can anyone show me how to write ant rules (`build.xml`) for creating a .jar file from  a .proto file?

Basically, I have written a functional `example.proto` and I can use the command line `protoc` to output java files.  But I want an ant rule to automate the above process as part of my build.  Can someone share a code snippet for a starting point?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is ancient, but it is still one of the top hits on Google for "ant protoc".

I was disappointed that I could not find an ant task for protoc, so I wrote my own: https://github.com/okorz001/ant-protoc

It is fairly primitive at the moment, but it supports nested filesets which was something I could not figure out how to do with exec hacks. (I am by no means an ant expert.) The task only executes protoc; you will need to use ant's stock javac and jar tasks in order to produce a jar.

Answer (score 2):

Proto compilation can also be done through ant exec.

```
  <!-- Generates protocol buffers. -->
  <property name="proto.srcs" value="../protos" />
  <target name="proto">
    <exec executable="protoc" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="--java_out=." />
        <arg value="--proto_path=${proto.srcs}" />
        <arg line="${proto.srcs}/my.proto" />
    </exec>
  </target>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need the [Ant Exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task to execute the binary to create the `.java` from the `.proto` files. The [Javac task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) will then compile these and the [Jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) builds your `.jar` file.

How do you tie all this together ? [This tutorial](http://www.developer.com/java/j2me/article.php/989631/Building-with-Ant-Introduction.htm) introduces Ant and how to make use of tasks like the above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've done to incorporate `protoc` into a project. Ideally I'd use a [`<mapper>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) but associating `.proto` files with their `.java` files isn't trivial, so in the meantime I just touch a marker file every time `protoc` runs.
The key is the [`<uptodate>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html) task which lets you set a property based on the relative ages of two sets of files (true if from is older than to, false otherwise).

```
<property name="proto.messages" value="proto"/>
<property name="proto.src" value="src-proto"/>
<property name="proto.markerfile" value="${proto.src}/markerfile"/>

<target name="init">
  <uptodate property="skip.protogen" targetfile="${proto.markerfile}">
    <srcfiles dir="${proto.messages}" />
  </uptodate>
  ...
</target>

<target name="clean">
  <delete dir="${proto.src}"/>
  ...
</target>

<target name="protoc" depends="init" unless="skip.protogen">
  <!-- delete first to ensure clean build -->
  <delete dir="${proto.src}"/>
  <mkdir dir="${proto.src}" />
  <apply executable="protoc" failonerror="true">
    <arg prefix="--java_out=" file="${proto.src}" />
    <arg prefix="--proto_path=" file="${proto.messages}" />
    <fileset dir="${proto.messages}" includes="**/*.proto" />
  </apply>
  <touch file="${proto.markerfile}" />
</target>

<target name="build" depends="init,protoc,...">
  <javac ...>
    <src path="${proto.src}"/>
    ...
  </javac>
</target>
```